# Call controller Codeigniter Eror

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to call check_login function but why even an error line number 10
[image]

```
public function cek_login() {
    $data = array('username' => $this->input->post('username', TRUE),
                    'password' => md5($this->input->post('password', TRUE))
        );
    $this->load->model('model_user'); // load model_user
    $hasil = $this->model_user->cek_user($data);
    if ($hasil->num_rows() == 1) {
        foreach ($hasil->result() as $sess) {
            $sess_data['logged_in'] = 'Sudah Loggin';
            $sess_data['uid'] = $sess->uid;
            $sess_data['username'] = $sess->username;
            $sess_data['level'] = $sess->level;
            $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
        }
        if ($this->session->userdata('level')=='admin') {
            redirect('admin/c_admin');
        }
        elseif ($this->session->userdata('level')=='member') {
            redirect('member/c_member');
        }       
    }
    else {
        echo "<script>alert('Gagal login: Cek username, password!');history.go(-1);</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set the `base_url` in your config file??

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'localhost/loginadm';

Comment: Make it `http://localhost/loginadm`. It should work

Comment: Tip: Don't use md5 for passwords very very unsecure for passwords. Use password hash like to create a password http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and to verify use callback http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php I don't know why people are still sing md5 for passwords?

Comment: I have already made, but it still can not call error

Comment: Weird that you are using a foreach here, there aren't multiples. and I second @Prabhu use: `http://localhost/{your_app_folder}` (if you have an app folder within localhost for different CI configs) otherwise just `http://localhost/`

Comment: Please be more specific, are you getting a 404 error?

Comment: I have already made, but it still can not call error

Comment: What is Line 10? The image you showed with the highlighted empty title tags is related how? Is it the form_open() causing the error?

Comment: no i do not get 404 error but i get this error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function form_open () in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ loginadm \ application \ views \ index.php on line 10

@Alex

Comment: open form form causes errors, I am confused how to fix it, I am still studying in PHP
@TimBrownlaw

Comment: @Aegz Ok, so we got to the actual issue and Alex has now answered it :)

Comment: sometimes you have to pull it out of 'em ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the form helper to use `form_open`. In your controller function that calls your view do: `$this->load->helper('form');` or you can do this in your view (not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Add this to your code